# Android email setup of Mail app results in a "Force Close"

Tags: motorola-droid, email

On the Motorola Droid I was successfully getting my corporate email for a year with no problems. On 11/09/2010 I started getting a security error when trying to retrieve email in the native Android Mail app. I tried tweaking a couple settings but ended up deleting my account credentials in order to re-enter them in an effort to bypass the security error. I know get an error every time I enter my account credentials and attempt to connect to our corporate exchange server.

I go through the following steps:

Open the mail app
Enter email address and password
Press Manual setup
Press Exchange
Modify Domain\Username and Server to contain correct corporate information
Insure "User secure connection (SSL)" and "Accept all SSL certificates" are checked
Press Next
App says "Checking incoming server settings"
Message pops up "Sorry! The application Email (process com.android.email) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again."

No combination of rebooting, clearing Mail app data and changing of SSL selections allows me to bypass this error.

**UPDATE**
According to Motorola Level 2 technical phone support the only solution to this issue is to restore the phone to it's factory settings.

Comment: Worse case scenario you could try a factory restore.  Make sure you backup everything first (if you are rooted, see TitaniumBackup)

Comment: That's odd I had the same thing happen to me on my Droid 1, after a few try's it worked. I wish I knew what was different on that last attempt, sorry it was a couple months ago...

Comment: Hi Andy, probably too late, but problems like these make excellent bug reports. If you can reproduce it and it force closes, then you should have downloaded something like Logcat from the Market and copied the bit of the log that has the error at the time when it force-closes, and report/paste it at b.android.com. Developers like me need this kind of info to improve the system, otherwise people keep running into this and everybody has to factory reset. Another way is a little persistance at Motorola's helpdesk. If it reproduces they should have taken a look at it if you ask me. Easy debugging!

Comment: This question should probably be closed as it is already solved and it is not clear what the question was.

Comment: Just a workaround suggestion but maybe you should give k9mail a test run. It is better for integration with corporate type mail servers than the stock client.

Comment: @Andy Brown: never, ever (well almost never :)  ) believe technical support when their only solution is a restore to factory settings ( or re-install the pc or phone ). It's there `deus ex machina` for not taking a problem seriously.

Answer (score 1):

Andy appears to be gone, so I'm going to post the answer since the problem is solved.

> According to Motorola Level 2 technical phone support the only solution to this issue is to restore the phone to it's factory settings.